# I am encountering error in writing a playbook in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am writing an ansible playbook and I get error "command is not a vlid attribute for a play"

My code:

```
---

-
 name: "This is our first play"
 hosts: tazhar
 tasks:
-
 name: "create a dummy file on server1"
 command: touch /tmp/ansible_dummywserver.txt
```

"your timely assistance will mean a lot"

Answer (score -1):

I think there is an issue related to the formatting of the YAML file (ansible-playbook).

```
---
- name: "This is our first play"
  hosts: tazhar
  tasks:
    -  name: "create a dummy file on server1"
       command: touch /tmp/ansible_dummywserver.txt
```

and if does not work for you use shell module  instead of command module.

Comment: Using the [`file` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html#file-module) would be much more indicated here.

Comment: @Zeitounator yes he can use the file module also, that's a better option. But in the above-asked question he was using a command module that's why I have suggested him the above approach.